# Java Selenium how to select child elements if they exist from multiple same parent elements

Tags: java, selenium, parent-child

I'm trying to get contact information off a webpage. Each contact is listed within an `info` class. The information I want is found in an `n`, `adr`, and `primary phone` class. What I want to do is iterate through each `info` element, check if it has those 3 child elements, and if all 3 exist add it to an ArrayList.

Heres an example of the basic parent-child relationship in the html

> ```
> <div class = "info">
>     <h2 class = "n">Header</h2>
>         <div class = "info-section info-primary">
>              <p class = adr> address here </p>
>         <ul class = "phones> phone# </u>
>         </div> 
> </div>
> ```

Thanks to those that helped me I was about to get only the child elements that I want. However, I need to check and make sure each parent element contains those child elements then add them to my list.

For Example: one contact could be

> ```
> <div class = "info">
>     <h2 class = "n">Company Name</h2>                                         
>         </div> 
> </div>
> ```

Since there is no phone or address listed I don't want to get them from the webpage, and move to the next contact.

Comment: Can you post sample html?

Comment: @socalcheesehead I added what the parent-child relationship looks like, does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all information you need is present on html by tags and classes, you just need to write a selector that be able to filter it to you, and not only using a Java code to do that.

Without a full HTML, is hard to imagine or think the better way to write a selector for you (CssSelector or XPath still looks the better options here). So, you can try the following CssSelector, or adapt it for what you need:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".info > h2 .info .adr, .info > h2 .phones"));
```

Comment: Yeah that looks like close to what I need. Does the ">" character denote a path to the element?

Comment: ">" means the imediate son of the element. Example, you have a html with this scructure: Html - body - div - h2 - a. This way, `h2` is the imediate son of `div`, so i'm able to obtain it using `div > h2`. If we check the body tag, it is not the imadiate parent of h2 element, so we can't use ">" to obtain the h2 element starting from body - it will return nothing (body > div > h2 should work). When we don't use the ">" character, we are saying to check al childs of an element, not only the imediate

Comment: Check it for more informations: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

Comment: After tinkering around with your suggestion I was able to get only the elements I want. However, some contacts don't have an address or phone number listed, how can I check for that and avoid adding them to my list?

Comment: It depends the situation: the html block with the class `phones` exists when a contact does not have a phone number? If it does not exist, your selector still works (when a path to a selector is not found, it just didn't return anything). However, if that html code exists, we should know how it is filled as default before write a CssSelector or Xpath

Comment: Yeah I see that if phone number doesn't exist it returns null. What I want is that if it returns null then do not add the company name, basically skip that contact and move to the next one.

Comment: don't skip. if you make it as separated selectors using `,` as i did with phonenumber. You can also write something similar as: `".info > h2 , .info> h2 .info .adr, .info > h2 .phones"` - There is a selector to obtain h2 element, another to adress and another to phone. It will get all elements that matchs `one or more` of these selectors. So, if a contact has only a header, it will return just the header and not null

Comment: Yeah, I get that but what I mean is that if any one of those returns null, I want everything to be null. That way I don't add a company without a phone number.

Comment: Oh, now i get it. This kind of logic is harder to do using selectors, just because `adr` is in a different son than `phones`. You can use a XPath to write all that you want, but it will result in a huge and ugly selector. Or just write in your back-end code to ignore your list of webElements if the quantity of elements is lesser than 3, but this way you need to assert that Company Name and Adress fields dont be duplicate in the page (because 2 name and 1 address can be considered valid)

Comment: Ah gotcha, I'll mess around with it but I think the hardest part is over now that I can get just the information I want. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Actually, there is one last thing that if you can solve will totally solve my issue. I split up the List<WebElements> into 3 seperate lists, one for `h2`, one for `adr`, and one for `phones`. Now sometimes `adr` and `phones` returns nothing since the element doesn't exist, is there a way to check for when it doesn't return anything and have it keep checking every element? I can only get it to check one element, then it stops.

Comment: I need to know how you write your code java-side to awnser. To be better to read, update your question with your code or create a new question - maybe someone can awnser you faster than me

Comment: Ok, I might do that. Thanks for the suggestion and all your help!